# Gap between centered button and border

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to convert the below image into CSS:

[image]

And this is what I came up with so far:

[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/99UJc/)

So my question is how can I  make that gap between the button and the bottom border of the box? Pls note that it needs to be flexible so the button could have any amount of text and stay always centered.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to fake the gap with `box-shadow`

```
button, .button {
    box-shadow: 5px 0 white,
                -5px 0 white;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/99UJc/2/)

Comment: Will it better to use the fake border?